# Create link from page title and add .pdf to the end

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, hyperlink, markup

I'm no good with jQuery, but I know what I want with it is possible.

Is there a way to take the page title, add it to an anchor link then add .pdf at the end? I make pdf files of all the page on our site, but would like the links created dynamically. And since the pdf's are using the page title, it makes sense to do it dynamically.

**Steps:**

1. Take page title
2. add ".pdf" to the end
3. Add the combined items to class="printbtn" which is the class name of the link.

   ```
   <a href="Tour Company - China Tours 2012.pdf" class="printbtn">Print this page</a>
   ```

I presume the script might need to add `%20` between spaces too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the page title:

```
var title = $('title').text();
```

To URL-encode that title:

```
var urlEncodedTitle = encodeURIComponent(title);
```

To add that to the given `a` element, add the file-type and amend the text to say 'print page':

```
$('.printbtn').attr('href',urlEncodedTitle + '.pdf').text('print page');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vC5K6/1/).

Bear in mind that the `$('.printbtn')` selector may find *multiple* elements with that class-name, so you might be better targeting by `id` rather than `class`: `$('#printbtn')`. If multiple elements are matched then the the text, and `href`, of each will be altered by the last line.

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/);
- [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Excellent! Very helpful, thank you. Now what would I need to add .pdf after the title and finally, how can I change the link to say 'Print Page' instead of listing the page title itself? Thanks again - very thorough.

Comment: Sorry I...lost track of the question, while I was composing the answer. Check the edited final line of jQuery, and I've updated the linked demo too. Oops..! =/

Comment: He he. No problem. This is exactly what I needed. And thank you for the references as well as the demo. I really should learn jQuery...